# Java Criteria API - how to use MySQL's ANY_VALUE

Tags: java, mysql, criteria-api

Is there any way to use Mysql ANY_VALUE in Criteria API?

I cant find any useful method in CriteriaBuilder, CriteriaQuery etc.

What i want achieve:

`SELECT cartID, date, ANY_VALUE(customerName) FROM table WHERE type='A' GROUP BY cartID, date;`

Why i need it? Because i dont want to add customerName to GROUP By clause ( its may be different for each row)

EDIT: I managed to do what i wanted by changing ANY_VALUE to MAX clause + if i want to ORDER BY customerName i need also to include MAX eg: 'ORDER BY MAX(customerName)

Comment: Strictly speaking, to use `ANY_VALUE`, which is MySQL specific, you would have to use a raw query.  But, taking a step back, why are using the above query?

Comment: Why not just drop the customerName completely. Seems pretty useless if you get an undeterministic customer's name just because you don't want to put it in group by.

Comment: Maybe this can be done using [CriteriaBuilder.function](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#function-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-javax.persistence.criteria.Expression...-)?

Comment: Data i want to fetch are orders. I want to get all distinct cartID's but query provides possibility to search by string, sort by columns from sorting etc. For customerName i need any of the customerName, doesnt matter. Thats why i need this column in select - without it i cant search in it or sort by this column

@JeroenSteenbeeke i will look at it

Comment: Thats what happens when i try to order by 'customerName' column without incluiding it in select/orderby 
` Expression #3 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column .customerName' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do what i wanted by changing ANY_VALUE to MAX clause + if i want to ORDER BY customerName i need also to include MAX eg: 'ORDER BY MAX(customerName)